# Install GCC 5.1 on Raspberry Pi 2 with Raspbian

Tags: linux, installation, debian, raspberry-pi, gcc

I would like to install GCC 5.1 (newest version - although 5.0 would be fine too) on my Raspberry Pi 2 with Raspbian (Debian jessie) installed. Sadly there is no debian package for GCC 5.1. I've tried building it from source, but it hasn't worked (mostly due to errors finding libraries). Any ideas?

Comment: Solve those errors by placing the ibraries where the build script is expecting them.  If you want GCC 5.1 you will have to build it yourself.

Comment: This would do better on raspberry pi stack exchange.

Comment: @Tyson it's not really a Raspberyy Pi specific question - or at least it shouldn't be

Comment: Following this worked for me: https://solarianprogrammer.com/2016/06/24/raspberry-pi-raspbian-install-gcc-compile-cpp-14-and-cpp-17-programs/ Cheers!